# Could anybody help identify this connector?

Tags: identification, connector, laptop, keyboard, lighting

Would any of you recognize the following connector ?

It's on a old Dell laptop motherboard (M3800). It's to connect the led circuit from the lit keyboard.

The flat brown cable from the lit keyboard has a width of 4-5mm. It has 4 printed wires.

The black latch is to lock the flat cable in place.

The white base surface of the connector is around 9mm by 6mm...

Thank you in advance for your lights :-)

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like a 0.5mm pitch FFC connector with a flip-lock; something like this:
https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Hirose%20PDFs/FH19C_FH19SC_Series.pdf

Comment: Given that the SO8 IC peeking out frmo under the yellow "pull" thing most definitely got pitch 1.27mm, this can't be 0.5mm pitch. I'd say it's 1.0mm, 1.27mm or 1.5mm.

Comment: Anyway, these kind of FFC connectors are rarely that critical. Get the FFC thickness, pitch and contact side right - then you can likely smack on anything there which matches those criteria.

Answer (score 0):

There's a chance that this could be a manufacturer specific part not publicly available, but it may conform to meet an existing compatibility spec. It looks like it could be similar to "Easy-On FFC/FPC connectors they are available in 0.5mm pitch and 1.0mm pitch formats." which some very basic information can be found at https://www.electronicsweekly.com/news/molex-styles-small-pitch-connector-reliability-2018-09/

There's a chance it may not be exactly the same one, but it still might be compatible. You could measure the contact spacing, and check that it matches the Molex 1mm pitch. If this is the same connector, it can be found pretty cheap at digikey: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/molex/2005280040/6099554

I'm guessing that you're looking to replace this one since it looks kind of like the left side is broken a little bit. If it were me, I would just spend a few bucks for a few and try the Molex if the pitch dimensions work out. Ribbon connections can be modified with scissors if it comes down to it. Before you try soldering it on, just check to see if it would clip to the cable first, you should be good if it does. Make sure you or someone you know are comfortable with this kind of thing before you try it out.

Comment: Thank you so much, Nate, for your detailed answer !!!